# Draw a polygon automatically through markers (points) in google maps

Tags: polygon, google-maps, google-maps-api, map-drawing, google-maps-api-3

I have a difficult situation, I'm trying to draw a polygon through markers (points), what I need is for the polygon to be drawn automatically after tracing the points.

The problem is that most of the polygons will be irregular, because the points indicate a route through the roads, and the polygon has to draw around those points with 100 meters margin on both sides, and manage to capture the positions Of the bookmarks in a table using javascript.

I put an image referring to what I want to do, the dotted blue line shows the polygon, and the black circles are the points.

[image: Example polygon]

I am using javascript and google maps api, I would like to know if what I want to do is possible without using a lot of mathematics and I would need to do it, sorry my English since I do not master it, my language is Spanish.

Comment: it can be done if you use a backend database (like postgis). see this convex hull example http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_map-markers_convexhull.asp

Answer (score 3):

if I've understood you correctly, what you want is called a [buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html).

This can be easily achieved with a library called [turfjs](http://turfjs.org/getting-started/). It is easy to integrate this with an alternative to google maps called [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com).

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mapsandropes/a53ofc1f/) is an example I've made of adding points to a leaflet map, connecting them with a polyline and buffering that polyline.

If you provide more details about how your data is stored I can be more specific about how you can get it onto the map.

Comment: This is great example, but I see that this forms with polylines, this way it is possible to calculate areas and objects that are inside the polygon?

Comment: Bigger polygon, now with area as a popup: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mapsandropes/82osLee8/7/). Turf has within functions too.